# Looping cosmos DB container to retrieve records in a batch using get-CosmosDbDocument

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I have got the Continuation token but just cant figure out a way of looping so i can retrieve the container records in a batch

```
Connect-AzAccount

$resourceGroupName = "resourceGroupName" 
$accountName = "accountName" 
$databaseName = "accountName"
$ParentContainer = "accountName" 
$childContainername = "childContainername" $count=0
$ResponseHeader=$null

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName   #For using the connection variable for retrieving and inserting the data

$documents = Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $ParentContainer -MaxItemCount 10 -ResponseHeader ([ref] $ResponseHeader)

$continuationToken = Get-CosmosDbContinuationToken -ResponseHeader $ResponseHeader

$doc = Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $ParentContainer -MaxItemCount 10 -ResponseHeader ([ref] $ResponseHeader) -ContinuationToken $continuationToken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code, try if this solves your problem:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$resourceGroupName = "resourceGroupName" 
$accountName = "accountName" 
$databaseName = "accountName"
$ParentContainer = "accountName" 
$childContainername = "childContainername" 
$count=0
$ResponseHeader=$null
$totalDocs = @()
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName   #For using the connection variable for retrieving and inserting the data
$documents = Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $ParentContainer -MaxItemCount 10 -ResponseHeader ([ref] $ResponseHeader)
$continuationToken = Get-CosmosDbContinuationToken -ResponseHeader $ResponseHeader
$totalDocs += $documents

while ($continuationToken) {
    $documents = Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $ParentContainer -MaxItemCount 10 -ResponseHeader ([ref] $ResponseHeader) -ContinuationToken $continuationToken
    $totalDocs += $documents
    $continuationToken = Get-CosmosDbContinuationToken -ResponseHeader $ResponseHeader
}
```